# Some webpages does not get load properly in JavaFX webview/webengine

Tags: javascript, webview, javafx, javafx-webengine

I am facing problem in loading some webpages correctly in JavaFX webview i.e. few javascript component does not work properly. For example, javascript validations for login on [this webpage](https://book.spicejet.com/LoginAgent.aspx) does not work in JavaFX webview.

The javascript for web engine is enabled `webEngine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
Still I am facing the issue. Is there any bug with JavaFX webview/webengine? I tested the same page in IE8, IE9 Latest version of Chrome and Firefox. It is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Java8. In that we can set UserAgent as safari, webkit etc. It solved my issue. :)

For Example:

```
webEngine.setUserAgent("AppleWebKit/537.44");
```

Answer (score 0):

For those following.

I don't know what the default user agent is but my advice is to explicitly set it.

I found inconsistent rendering of pages into WebView from a particular location (first page would be as expected, subsequent not).I was using an immediate reload() following load() as a hack fix but then realised the UA was probably the cause.

```
engine.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
Chrome/44.0.2403.155 Safari/537.36");
```